# Intents and Contents

Tags: android

Im trying to create a simple pub quiz game so iv made my layout with the two teams.  When the image button is clicked i want a menu to appear with a questions and they have to select an answer.  I am just confused how to bring a small menu when the button is clicked.i know i can use these i just dont understand how?

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

Comment: Your questions a very general, try to ask more specific questions. No one will post a complete solution for your problem.

Comment: Be specific please...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) class and the [Dialog tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) on the Android Developer website.